# Using a diode to cancel out voltage sources?

Tags: voltage

The following parallel circuit has the voltage sources in opposition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWPYzM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My attempt is to have V2 cancel with V3.
With the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuR4JI.png)</sup>

Where the diode would block out V2,V3 having a series circuit between V2,V3 and they would cancel out? Leaving the V = 5.

Comment: The first schematic yields the following 'equation':  \$5 = 10\$.  The second schematic is at least consistent.  The voltage across the diode is \$V_D = -5V\$.  I honestly don't have a clue what you're trying to do though.  What do you mean by *"have V2 cancel with V3"*?  This is not ordinary EE speak that you're using.

Comment: I'm teaching myself circuitry so excuse my terrible terminology. However, the second circuit has been adjusted. The goal is to see the possibility of having "V=?" = 5V from V1, and V2 canceling out with V2 since they are in opposition. But why would the voltage across the diode become -5? How could it conduct where V2 and V3 are greater than that?

Comment: Key, a diode doesn't conduct when the voltage across is negative.  In your circuit, the voltage across the diode is given by an *elementary* application of KVL:  \$V_D = 5V - 10V = -5V\$.  Without a reference node, the voltage at the node marked \$V = ?\$ is ambiguous - voltage with respect to *what*?

Comment: Here is where my assumption was wrong, I assumed due to the diode V2 could cancel out with V3 since they are somewhat in "series" and in opposition, therefore the voltage across the diode would be 5V. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: V2 and V3 are in parallel. Since they are the same voltage, they can be considered as a single voltage source.  D1 will be reverse biased so no current will flow through it.

Comment: @PeterBennett What if they we're un-equal voltages? Say 5V and 10V?

Comment: Key: if two unequal idea voltage sources are connected in parallel, infinite current will flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltages can only be put in parallel if they are identical, otherwise a large current (limited only by wiring resistance and the voltage sources themselves) will flow from the higher to lower voltage. In your theoretical circuit there is no resistance, so the current will be infinite!

To get voltages to 'cancel out' you have to wire them in *series* with opposite polarity. But what is series and what is parallel? Components in *parallel* are wired across each other, and the current splits into separate paths as it passes through them. In a *series* circuit the components are connected one after the other, so the current flows first through one and then through the other.

So consider the following circuit with two voltage sources - are they in series, or in parallel?

[image]

The way the circuit is drawn makes it look like the voltages are in parallel, with a small resistance between them. But if we redraw the circuit like this...

[image]

...we can see that they are actually in series. Current flows around the circuit going through each component in turn, and at no point does it split into two separate paths.

Now add up all the voltage sources. From A to C we have +5V, and from C to B we have -10V. Therefore the voltage from A to B is +5V + -10V = -5V. V1 has effectively 'cancelled out' half the voltage from V2.

Finally, let's add up *all* the voltages in the circuit in any one direction (eg. A to C, plus C to B, plus B to A). We get a total of 5 - 10 + 5 = 0V. This principle, known as Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, is true for *any* closed network; the sum of all voltages around the loop must add up to zero.

Comment: If you try to wire two different voltage sources in parallel then a series circuit will be created _between_ them. So in your first circuit, V2 and V3 are in parallel (creating a single 10V source) but they are in _series_ with V1. Where possible you should draw the components and wiring so that parallel and series configurations are obvious, like in your second circuit.

Comment: Wait, so in theory if V2 was 9V instead of 10V then the circuit will become a series with a total voltage of -1V?

Comment: Yes, V2 and V3 would form a series circuit with a driving voltage of -1V (and infinite current because there is no resistance in the loop!).

Comment: I didn't add a resistor for the sake of understanding the theory, but that's simple. I can add a 1 Ohm resistor to make current flow equal I = V/R.

Comment: In that case if V2 was 9V the total voltage in reverse bias to D1 is -1V meaning V1 will conduct at 4V.

Comment: About the infinite current, that's not true because the wire itself has resistance... in the ideal world current can never be infinite(even in a superconductor).

Comment: In the ideal world of theoretical circuits it could happen, but in the **real** world you cannot have dissimilar voltage sources in parallel. There will always be some resistance in _series_ which limits the current.

Comment: Thanks, but just to be sure... If V2 was 9V, D1 will conduct and the voltage at the point"V=?" is 4V? Since -1V is remaining and 5V from V1.

Comment: Am I correct there Bruce? The total voltage would be 4V from V1(5V) and -1V from the total between V2 and V3? Therefore D1 will conduct?

Comment: No. V2 is still 9V and V3 is 10V, so the voltage across them must be somewhere between 9V and 10V, and the diode would not conduct. The only place where -1V occurs is in the series circuit *between* V2 and V3.